# Pandas: Looking to avoid a for loop when creating a nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Here is my data:

df:

```
id sub_id
A  1
A  2
B  3
B  4
```

and I have the following array:

```
[[1,2],
[2,5],
[1,4],
[7,8]]
```

Here is my code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

sub_id_array_dict = defaultdict(dict)
for i, s, a in zip(df['id'].to_list(), df['sub_id'].to_list(), arrays):
    sub_id_array_dict[i][s] = a
```

Now, my actual dataframe includes a total of 100M rows (unique sub_id) with 500K unique ids. Ideally, I'd like to avoid a for loop.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `arrays` variable has same number of rows as in the Dataframe,

```
df['value'] = arrays
```

Convert into dictionary by grouping

```
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x.sub_id, x.value))).to_dict()
```

Output

```
{'A': {1: [1, 2], 2: [2, 5]}, 'B': {3: [1, 4], 4: [7, 8]}}
```